# Pasar de una lista de strings a un array de integers

Tags: python, array, lista

Necesito pasar una lista de strings a integers, pero los strings están en Hexadecimal y separados por una coma:

```
[b'41828,845148' b'41828,899349' b'41828,893863' b'15094,747063'
 b'15094,751849' b'15094,771319' b'15058,112976' b'15072,057815'
 b'15072,350048' b'15045,828658' b'15064,450596' b'15064,831146'
 b'15033,438389' b'15057,515187' b'15057,706190' b'14571,152502'
 b'14799,577474' b'14791,525846' b'14797,452731' b'14797,466759'
 b'14033,529076' b'14515,792605' b'14476,048055' b'13606,645333']
```

A cada lado de la coma hay un entero distinto y espero obtener, por ejemplo `[41828, 845148]` para el primer item, para luego pasarlo a decimal.

Lo que intentaba era separa los componentes de la lista, emplear un espacio, para luego hacer un recorrido convertir en array y luego pasar a decimal. Pero me aparece un error al intentar sustituir la `,` por el espacio.

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberias agregar que has intentado o investigado, así como explicar la salida esperada. Lo que tienes son cadenas de bytes (ASCII), ¿cada subcadena a ambos lados de la coma es un entero distinto? para b'41828,845148' que esperas ¿`[41828, 845148]`? ¿`[268328, 8671560]`? ¿Otra cosa?

Comment: Hola, si, a cada lado de la coma hay un integer  distinto y espero obener [41828, 845148]  para luego pasarlo a decimal. Lo que intetaba era separa los componentes de la lista, emplear un espacio, para luego hacer un recorrido convertir en array y luego pasar a decimal. Pero me aparece un error al intentar sustituir la , por el espacio

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo muestras, lo que tienes es una lista  con **una sola cadena de bytes**, es idéntico a :

```
[b'41828,84514841828,89934941828,89386315094,74706315094,75184915094,77131915058,11297615072,05781515072,35004815045,82865815064,45059615064,83114615033,43838915057,51518715057,70619014571,15250214799,57747414791,52584614797,45273114797,46675914033,52907614515,79260514476,04805513606,645333']
```

Los espacios no forman parte de la cadena, son totalmente ignorados por el parser del intérprete.

Es tal caso, solo debes separar por la coma y usar posteriormente `int` para convertir la cadena en entero decimal:

```
lista = [
    b'41828,845148' b'41828,899349' b'41828,893863' b'15094,747063'
    b'15094,751849' b'15094,771319' b'15058,112976' b'15072,057815'
    b'15072,350048' b'15045,828658' b'15064,450596' b'15064,831146'
    b'15033,438389' b'15057,515187' b'15057,706190' b'14571,152502'
    b'14799,577474' b'14791,525846' b'14797,452731' b'14797,466759'
    b'14033,529076' b'14515,792605' b'14476,048055' b'13606,645333']

dec_list = [int(num, 16) for item in lista for num in item.decode().split(",")]
```

> ```
> >>> dec_list
>
> [268328,
>  9092789966888,
>  9454105139240,
>  9429704593556,
>  8001627967636,
>  8046697861268,
>  8182744305752,
>  1179360776306,
>  375831744626,
>  3642207850565,
>  8969594687588,
>  4743143444580,
>  9006888341555,
>  4639513727063,
>  5588162531415,
>  7722770711921,
>  1453043304345,
>  6009854707601,
>  5658692896663,
>  4752164341655,
>  4838105628723,
>  5673775613205,
>  8325262558326,
>  309326853638,
>  6574899]
> ```

Ten en cuenta que ésto es muy diferente a ésto:

```
lista = [
    b'41828,845148',  b'41828,899349',  b'41828,893863',  b'15094,747063', 
    b'15094,751849',  b'15094,771319',  b'15058,112976',  b'15072,057815', 
    b'15072,350048',  b'15045,828658',  b'15064,450596',  b'15064,831146', 
    b'15033,438389',  b'15057,515187',  b'15057,706190',  b'14571,152502', 
    b'14799,577474',  b'14791,525846',  b'14797,452731',  b'14797,466759', 
    b'14033,529076',  b'14515,792605',  b'14476,048055',  b'13606,645333']
```

En cuyo caso el mismo código anterior serviría también:

```
dec_list = [int(num,  16) for item in lista for num in item.decode().split(",")]
```

> ```
> >>>dec_list)
> [268328,
>  8671560,
>  268328,
>  9016137,
>  268328,
>  8992867,
>  86164,
>  7630947,
>  86164,
>  7673929,
>  86164,
>  7803673,
>  86104,
>  1124726,
>  86130,
>  358421,
>  86130,
>  3473480,
>  86085,
>  8554072,
>  86116,
>  4523414,
>  86116,
>  8589638,
>  86067,
>  4424585,
>  86103,
>  5329287,
>  86103,
>  7365008,
>  83313,
>  1385730,
>  83865,
>  5731444,
>  83857,
>  5396550,
>  83863,
>  4532017,
>  83863,
>  4613977,
>  81971,
>  5410934,
>  83221,
>  7939589,
>  83062,
>  294997,
>  79366,
>  6574899]
> ```

O si queremos separa cada pareja de enteros:

```
dec_list = [[int(num,  16) for num in item.decode().split(",")] for item in lista]
```

> ```
> >>> dec_list
> [[268328, 8671560],
>  [268328, 9016137],
>  [268328, 8992867],
>  [86164, 7630947],
>  [86164, 7673929],
>  [86164, 7803673],
>  [86104, 1124726],
>  [86130, 358421],
>  [86130, 3473480],
>  [86085, 8554072],
>  [86116, 4523414],
>  [86116, 8589638],
>  [86067, 4424585],
>  [86103, 5329287],
>  [86103, 7365008],
>  [83313, 1385730],
>  [83865, 5731444],
>  [83857, 5396550],
>  [83863, 4532017],
>  [83863, 4613977],
>  [81971, 5410934],
>  [83221, 7939589],
>  [83062, 294997],
>  [79366, 6574899]]
> ```

- `bytes.decode()` convierte la cadena de bytes a `str` (por defecto se usa UTF-8 como codificación).
- `str.split(",")` rompe la cadena usando la cadena "," como separador.
- `int(num, 16)` convierte la cadena `num` en `int` usando como base 16, hexadecimal.